# What is the best type to store a signature on chain?

Tags: solidity, signature, bytes, ecrecover

I'm signing a hash and getting a string with 130 bytes.  What is the best way to store this signature later in my smart contract?

Should I just go ahead and split it into r,s, and v and store it in four byte32 vars and one byte2 var or should I use bytes?  Or String?  Which is cheaper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial cost of storing it in a `bytes` is approximately 20% more than using 4x `bytes32` and 1x `bytes2`.

You should also consider what your contract is going to do with the signature. If it's going to do some computation on the parts, you may not want the overhead of splitting the `bytes` into pieces again.

On the other hand, if you're only going to pass the signature around as a whole, using just one `bytes` variable will make the code a lot easier to read.

I hope this helps somewhat :-)